# vue 2.0 and vue-router 2.0 build SPA, router-view did not update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

Build A Single page app with vue 2 and vue-router 2 and vuex 2, but  do not update

/src/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
sync(store, router)
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

/src/router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import routes from './routes'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
export default router
```

/src/router/routes.js

```
import loader from './loader'
const routes = [
  { path: '/index', name: 'index', component: (r) => require(['./../views/index.vue'], r) }
]
export default routes
```

/src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {}
})
export default store
```

/src/view/index.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Hello index</h1>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import loader from './../../../router/loader'
export default {
  name: 'index',
  created () {
    console.log('This is index')
  }
}
</script>
```

/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link :to="'index'">index</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  mounted () {
    console.log('Hello App')
  }
}
</script>
```

I do not know what's wrong with the code, the `<router-view>` do not update when I change the route.

Comment: Actually, the router did not "start up" yet, the vue dev tools just shows me a `<APP>` node, why?

Comment: And the dev tool Vuex shows that store state.route is empty

Answer (score 1):

I think your app is not properly initialized yet. You are starting your app as follows:

```js
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

You have the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...App`, which is not necessary - it is used to convert array items to function args, and not correct in this context. Instead you should use the render function as provided in [webpack template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) :

```js
/* eslint-disable-line no-new */
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

Also you have attempted to `import loader` in routes and index, which is not necessary if you are using `vue-cli`.

Maybe you can start with the [webpack template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) as base and slowly add functionality one step at a time: start with route definitions and your route components, ensure that everything works, and finally add vuex.

Answer (score 0):

`$mount('#app')` is fine, I think the problem is your routes.js

Try this instead:

```
import Index from './../views/index.vue'

const routes = [
  { path: '/index', name: 'index', component: Index }
]
```

And here is a working webpack template which is already configured `vue-router` and `vuex` properly, you can initialize this template via `vue-cli`, for your reference: https://github.com/CodinCat/vue-webpack-plus